# How to multiplex AF_INET sockets to a daemon and get the information about the original port in the application?

Tags: linux, sockets

I would like to write a daemon that is available on a large number of AF_INET-SOCK_STREAM and AF_INET-SOCK_DGRAM sockets for network debugging purposes.

To avoid excessive resource usage I want to avoid opening a large number of ports on the application layer but try to multiplex the connections per socket type on lower layers.
Knowledge of the original incoming port on the application layer is a requirement.

I have successfully implemented a daemon that listens on an AF_INET SOCK_STREAM socket that is multiplexed by an iptables REDIRECT rule. The original incoming port of the connection can be retrieved by calling getsockopt with SO_ORIGINAL_DST. As I understand this does not work with AF_INET SOCK_DGRAM.

I have also successfully implemented a daemon that listens on an AF_INET SOCK_DGRAM socket that is multiplexed by an iptables TPROXY rule. The original incoming port of the connection can be retrieved by using recvmsg() and consuming the available ancillary message containing information about the connection before multiplexing. As I understand this does not work with AF_INET SOCK_STREAM.

Is there a transport-layer-agnostic way of multiplexing such socket connections and retrieving information about the original incoming port? Possibly even suitable for protocols like SCTP or DCCP?

Comment: "Is there a transport-layer-agnostic way of multiplexing such socket connections and retrieving information about the original incoming port?"  That sounds more like a question for superuser than stackoverflow.   things like iptables rules are generally off topic here.

Comment: Looks appropriate for SO, as it's not so much about iptables as it is about programming in the (proxy) server, but: expecting something agonostic between SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM is a bit optimistic, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

With TCP you have a connection. The target port for this connection is the same for all packets inside this connection. In this case each connected socket (result from `accept`) equals to a single connection and the incoming port is a property of this socket. It does not matter in this case if the listening socket will accept connections on multiple ports, all what matters is the connected socket.

With UDP you don't have a connection. Instead the same socket is used to receive packages from multiple clients and in your case to multiple incoming ports. Source and destination IP and port are thus a property of each packet and not of the socket.

That's why you need different interfaces to retrieve the original incoming port: a socket based for TCP and a packet based for UDP.